# The difference between /usr/local/etc vs /etc/apache2 for apache running on Mac OS

Tags: php, macos, apache, homebrew

Hi I am very new to both apache and mac.
I had set up apache through Homebrew and as far as I understand so far,
apache from mac runs on OS level, but apache through Homebrew runs on user level. I think that is why mac apache stays in /etc level directory while Homebrew apache stays in /user/local/etc level.

However, I found out that both httpd.conf files differ from each other. Especially I am experiencing a problem that php doesn't render in a virtual host. I tried to fix the problem, but it seems like every solutions in the internet talks about httpd.conf for mac apache.

I am quite confused of what I am doing right now. It will be great if anyone of you guys can explain me how these apaches work different. Thanks!

Comment: Your analysis is largely correct. Did you have a specific programming question we could help with?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks Mark. I just figured out the php rendering issue. My big confusion was that I thought httpd.conf from brew apache override httpd.conf for mac apache which was very stupid... As far as now, no I got the solution for my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Default apache path would be:

```
/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

homebrew apache path

```
/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf
```

You can check how many apaches are running in your system:

```
which -a apachectl
```

---

Default apache:

```
/usr/sbin/apachectl
```

Homebrew:

```
/usr/local/bin/apachectl
```

The command below for default apache

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

You may use this for the homebrew apache

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/apachectl restart
```